# Fade in and out elements with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Right now Im having two issues with the code that Im not able to fix:

1) In jsfiddle the items fade in when scrolling down, but when I try it with sublime (or notepad ++) the fade in only works when refreshing the page and on scroll-up.

2) For the fade out I tried to add this part to the code but its no working. What is worse its actually breaking the first fade in (this issue happens in both jsfiddle and local)

```
 //check if this current container is within view
    if ((element_bottom_position >= window_top_position) &&
      (element_top_position <= window_bottom_position)) {
      $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},500);
    } else {
          $(this).animate({'opacity':'0'},500);
      }
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ja5nz1ux/

(For the moment I'm doing everything in the html itself)

The code:

```html
<HTML>

<HEAD>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .timeline {
      --uiTimelineMainColor: var(--timelineMainColor, #008080);
      --uiTimelineSecondaryColor: var(--timelineSecondaryColor, #fff);
      position: relative;
      padding-top: 3rem;
      padding-bottom: 3rem;
    }
    
    .timeline:before {
      content: "";
      width: 4px;
      height: 100%;
      /* Color line */
      background-color: #2e4053;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
    }
    
    .timeline__group {
      position: relative;
      opacity: 1;
    }
    
    .timeline__group:not(:first-of-type) {
      margin-top: 4rem;
    }
    
    .timeline__year {
      padding: .5rem 1.5rem;
      color: var(--uiTimelineSecondaryColor);
      background-color: var(--uiTimelineMainColor);
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
    }
    
    .timeline__box {
      position: relative;
      opacity: 0;
    }
    
    .timeline__box:not(:last-of-type) {
      margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
    
    .timeline__box:before {
      content: "";
      width: 100%;
      height: 2px;
      /* color line middle */
      background-color: #c39bd3;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      z-index: -1;
    }
    
    .timeline__date {
      min-width: 65px;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      padding: .5rem 1.5rem;
      text-align: center;
      /* color box */
      background-color: #008080;
      color: var(--uiTimelineSecondaryColor);
    }
    
    .timeline__day {
      font-size: 2rem;
      font-weight: 700;
      display: block;
    }
    
    .timeline__month {
      display: block;
      font-size: .8em;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    
    .timeline__post {
      padding: 1.5rem 2rem;
      border-radius: 2px;
      /* color box text */
      border-left: 3px solid #c39bd3;
      box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .12), 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .24);
      background-color: var(--uiTimelineSecondaryColor);
    }
    
    @media screen and (min-width: 641px) {
      .timeline:before {
        left: 30px;
      }
      .timeline__group {
        padding-top: 55px;
        opacity: 1;
      }
      .timeline__box {
        padding-left: 80px;
      }
      .timeline__box:before {
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
      }
      .timeline__date {
        top: 50%;
        margin-top: -27px;
      }
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
      .timeline:before {
        left: 0;
      }
      .timeline__group {
        padding-top: 40px;
        opacity: 1;
      }
      .timeline__box {
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-top: 70px;
      }
      .timeline__box:before {
        top: 90px;
      }
      .timeline__date {
        top: 0;
      }
    }
    
    .timeline {
      --timelineMainColor: #4557bb;
      font-size: 16px;
    }
    /*
   =====
   DEMO
   =====
   */
    
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
      html {
        font-size: 62.5%;
      }
    }
    
    @media (max-width: 767px) {
      html {
        font-size: 55%;
      }
    }
    
    body {
      font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Open Sans, Ubuntu, Fira Sans, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
      font-size: 1.6rem;
      color: # #008080;
      background-color: #f0f0f0;
      margin: 0;
      -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
      overflow-y: scroll;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    p {
      margin-top: 0;
      margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
      line-height: 1.5;
    }
    
    p:last-child {
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    
    .page {
      max-width: 800px;
      padding: 10rem 2rem 3rem;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      order: 1;
    }
  </style>
</HEAD>

<BODY>

  <div class="page">
    <div class="timeline">

      <div class="timeline__group">
        <div class="timeline__box">
          <div class="timeline__date">
            <span class="timeline__month">Day</span>
            <span class="timeline__day">1</span>
          </div>
          <div class="timeline__post">
            <div class="timeline__content">
              <p> test 1 </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="timeline__group">
        <div class="timeline__box">
          <div class="timeline__date">
            <span class="timeline__month">Day</span>
            <span class="timeline__day">2</span>
          </div>
          <div class="timeline__post">
            <div class="timeline__content">
              <p> test 2 </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="timeline__group">
        <div class="timeline__box">
          <div class="timeline__date">
            <span class="timeline__month">Day</span>
            <span class="timeline__day">3</span>
          </div>
          <div class="timeline__post">
            <div class="timeline__content">
              <p> test 3 </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="timeline__group">
        <div class="timeline__box">
          <div class="timeline__date">
            <span class="timeline__month">Day</span>
            <span class="timeline__day">4</span>
          </div>
          <div class="timeline__post">
            <div class="timeline__content">
              <p> test 4 </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="timeline__group">
        <div class="timeline__box">
          <div class="timeline__date">
            <span class="timeline__month">Day</span>
            <span class="timeline__day">5</span>
          </div>
          <div class="timeline__post">
            <div class="timeline__content">
              <p> test 5 </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="timeline__group">
        <div class="timeline__box">
          <div class="timeline__date">
            <span class="timeline__month">Day</span>
            <span class="timeline__day">6</span>
          </div>
          <div class="timeline__post">
            <div class="timeline__content">
              <p> test 6 </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="timeline__group">
        <div class="timeline__box">
          <div class="timeline__date">
            <span class="timeline__month">Day</span>
            <span class="timeline__day">7</span>
          </div>
          <div class="timeline__post">
            <div class="timeline__content">
              <p> test 7 </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="timeline__group">
        <div class="timeline__box">
          <div class="timeline__date">
            <span class="timeline__month">Day</span>
            <span class="timeline__day">8</span>
          </div>
          <div class="timeline__post">
            <div class="timeline__content">
              <p> test 8 </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="timeline__group">
        <div class="timeline__box">
          <div class="timeline__date">
            <span class="timeline__month">Day</span>
            <span class="timeline__day">9</span>
          </div>
          <div class="timeline__post">
            <div class="timeline__content">
              <p> test 9 </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="timeline__group">
        <div class="timeline__box">
          <div class="timeline__date">
            <span class="timeline__month">Day</span>
            <span class="timeline__day">10</span>
          </div>
          <div class="timeline__post">
            <div class="timeline__content">
              <p> test 10 </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="timeline__group">
        <div class="timeline__box">
          <div class="timeline__date">
            <span class="timeline__month">Day</span>
            <span class="timeline__day">11</span>
          </div>
          <div class="timeline__post">
            <div class="timeline__content">
              <p> test 11 </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="timeline__group">
        <div class="timeline__box">
          <div class="timeline__date">
            <span class="timeline__month">Day</span>
            <span class="timeline__day">12</span>
          </div>
          <div class="timeline__post">
            <div class="timeline__content">
              <p> test 12 </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="timeline__group">
        <div class="timeline__box">
          <div class="timeline__date">
            <span class="timeline__month">Day</span>
            <span class="timeline__day">13</span>
          </div>
          <div class="timeline__post">
            <div class="timeline__content">
              <p> test 13 </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="timeline__group">
        <div class="timeline__box">
          <div class="timeline__date">
            <span class="timeline__month">Day</span>
            <span class="timeline__day">14</span>
          </div>
          <div class="timeline__post">
            <div class="timeline__content">
              <p> test 14 </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="timeline__group">
        <div class="timeline__box">
          <div class="timeline__date">
            <span class="timeline__month">Day</span>
            <span class="timeline__day">15</span>
          </div>
          <div class="timeline__post">
            <div class="timeline__content">
              <p> test 15 </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="timeline__group">
        <div class="timeline__box">
          <div class="timeline__date">
            <span class="timeline__month">Day</span>
            <span class="timeline__day">16</span>
          </div>
          <div class="timeline__post">
            <div class="timeline__content">
              <p> test 16 </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>



    </div>
  </div>


  <script>
    var $animation_elements = $('.timeline__box');
    var $window = $(window);

    function check_if_in_view() {
      var window_height = $window.height();
      var window_top_position = $window.scrollTop();
      var window_bottom_position = (window_top_position + window_height);

      $.each($animation_elements, function() {
        var $element = $(this);
        var element_height = $element.outerHeight();
        var element_top_position = $element.offset().top;
        var element_bottom_position = (element_top_position + element_height);

        //check to see if this current container is within viewport
        if ((element_bottom_position >= window_top_position) &&
          (element_top_position <= window_bottom_position)) {
          $(this).animate({
            'opacity': '1'
          }, 500);
        }
      });
    }

    $window.on('scroll resize', check_if_in_view);
    $window.trigger('scroll');
  </script>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not work on sublime, notepad ++ or any other IDE which opens output in you browser (not in frame like online platforms like **Jsfiddle**) until you don't write

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

because without this your **$window.height()** will not work properly

```
var window_height = $window.height();
```

This will give you the value of whole scrollable content.

and also when you scroll all over, the opacity of all the elements having class  **timeline__box** become 1

[As shown in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMYDX.png)

```
//check if this current container is within view
    if ((element_bottom_position >= window_top_position) &&
      (element_top_position <= window_bottom_position)) {
      $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},500);
    } else {
          $(this).animate({'opacity':'0'},500);
      }
```

If you scroll a little bit, **check_if_in_view()** function called over multiple time and as you added a delay of 500 ms There for it will remain at opacity of 1 for long time.
It will be easy to understand if you apply code below the elements starts **blinking**. Therefore it will not work

```
//check if this current container is within view
        if ((element_bottom_position >= window_top_position) &&
          (element_top_position <= window_bottom_position)) {
          $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},500);              
          $(this).animate({'opacity':'0'},500);
          }
```

I hope you will understand

Comment: That did work, thanks!
How do you advice me to handle the fade in and out?

Comment: There are various animate on scroll (AOS) libraries you can find it on internet. Try [This link](https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/)